# Mac OS Ventura 13.5.2 - Unable to compile

Tags: compilation-error

My mac upgraded to Ventura 13.5.2 and when I tried to compile using TexShop I now get the following error message.  I have used LateX (AmSTeX,Tex) for quite sometime, however, I am not familiar with this type of error message (where it appears to be in the master command file, I think). Any suggestion on how to clear this error.  I believe it is something simple since it only happened after my upgrade.  [image: Error screenshot]

Comment: the error is in your `.out` file for bookmarks, `\BOOKMARK` command has been truncated, delete the file and let the package write a new one

Comment: I am a novice when it comes to making changes to "files".  I am a technical typist and have not had to make changes like that.  If you don't mind, can you explain how do I make these changes?  If this is too much to ask, I understand and will research the process for making the change.

Comment: You say you use TeXshop. Under the "File" menu, click on the final item in the drop-down list, "Trash Aux Files". Then try to (re)compile your tex file.

Comment: David, thank you ...that was the problem.  I figured out how to find and delete the .out file.  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your `.out` file for bookmarks. The `\BOOKMARK` command has been truncated, delete the file and let the package write a new `.out` file.